# Cannot create index - bad index key pattern

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

After some activities with my database, I lost my index. I had these indexes:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "collection.statement"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "name" : 1
    },
    "name" : "name_1",
    "ns" : "collection.statement"
}
```

and now I have only first one.
I've entered this command

```
db.collection.createIndex({
    "v" : 1, 
    "unique" : true, 
    "key" :{ "name" : 1 }, 
    "name" : "name_1", 
    "ns" : "collection.statement"
})
```

and I only get and error message that i have a bad index key pattern.
Please, help me, how to return this index? What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

You attempt includes internal aspects of the index (`"v" : 1`), you just need to supply the field(s) and an order for each and the `unique` instruction.

More details [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/).